# How to remove substring from each line of text file

Tags: c#, regex

Let's say I have some data in the following format...

```
<sdf<xml>....</xml>...
.........<smc<xml>....
...</xml>...<ueo<xml>.
.... and goes on......
```

My objective is to read this data line by line from a file and then delete the 4 preceding characters before any `<xml>` tag detected. In the above case, it would be `<sdf`, `<smc` and `<ueo` that would be deleted.

I've written the following right now.. the regex at the moment is wrong and not working..

```
while((line = reader.ReadLine()) !=null)
{
  writer.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(line, @"(?i)</(xml)(?!>)",</$1>),, string.Empty);         
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact data? I don't think your real problem is *removing some chars from each line.*

Comment: Are the actual xml tags named `<xml>`?

Comment: Define "wrong and not working"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general idea and loop structure is fine. It's simply the regex matching that needs a little work:

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    writer.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(line, @"....<xml>", "<xml>"));
```

If you want this to work with any pattern of the form `<...<tag>` you can use:

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    writer.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(line, @"<[^<>]{3}<([^<>]+)>", "<$1>"));
```

Comment: Couldn't be any clearer +1.

Comment: Just found out that my data also contains data in the form of `<..<tag>`.. How would I go about taking care of both scenario's? `<..<tag>` & `<...<tag>`

Comment: @32vihar: In the first example, replace `....` with `....?` (which makes the last any-character match optional), and in the second, replace the `{3}` with a `{2,3}` (2 to 3 non-angle-bracket characters instead of always 3). I encourage you to play around with the regex in an online regex tester -- it will help you understand how it works for next time you need to write a regex :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

```
while((line = reader.ReadLine()) !=null)
{
  writer.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(line, @"(?is).{4}(?=<(\w+)\b[^>]*>.*?</\1>)" ,""), string.Empty);         
}
```

Comment: It errors out saying argument missing

Comment: try now, it's not with the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string testData = "<sdf<xml><something/></xml><smc<xml><something/><ueo<xml><something /></xml>";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<string, string> stripInvalidXml = input => {
                Func<int, bool> shouldSkip = index =>
                {
                    var xI = index + 4; //add 4 to see what's after the current 4 characters
                    if (xI >= (input.Length - 5)) //make sure adding 4 and the length of <xml> doesn't exceed end of input
                        return false;
                    if (input.Substring(xI, 5) == "<xml>") //check if the characters 4 indexes after the current character are <xml>
                        return true; //skip the current index
                    return false; //don't skip
                };
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
                {
                    //loop through each character and see if the characters 4 after are <xml>
                    char c = input[i];
                    if (shouldSkip(i))
                        i += 3; //if should skip, we are already on the first character, so add 3 more to skip to skip 4 characters
                    else
                        sb.Append(c);
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            };
            Console.WriteLine(stripInvalidXml(testData));
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Looping Replace is ineffecient as all get out, this method loops through each character only once and does a manual look ahead.  It doesn't do a replace because it builds a new string with StringBuilder as it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
writer.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"<.{3}(<\w*>)", "$1"), string.Empty);
```

This is assuming that the solutions should match tags that aren't specifically named `<xml></xml>`.